# ESP8266 board stopped installing via board manager

Tags: failed-installation, arduino-esp8266

I have tried the usual procedure of adding `https://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json` in preference. Then opened board manager, found ESP8266 by ESP8266 community and tried to install 2.6.3 by clicking install. After downloading around 5 MB of data, the download stops. I have tried to download the zip file directly and was successful. I could update other boards without any problem. I am using Arduino 1.8.10 on windows 10. Disabled the antivirus and deleted the Arduino15 folder in AppData\Local multiple times with no effect.
The error

```
Error downloading https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/releases/download/2.6.3/esp8266-2.6.3.zip
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Exception: Error downloading https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/releases/download/2.6.3/esp8266-2.6.3.zip
   at cc.arduino.contributions.packages.ui.ContributionManagerUI.lambda$onInstallPressed$2(ContributionManagerUI.java:175)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error downloading https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/releases/download/2.6.3/esp8266-2.6.3.zip
   at cc.arduino.contributions.DownloadableContributionsDownloader.download(DownloadableContributionsDownloader.java:144)
   at cc.arduino.contributions.DownloadableContributionsDownloader.download(DownloadableContributionsDownloader.java:78)
   at cc.arduino.contributions.DownloadableContributionsDownloader.download(DownloadableContributionsDownloader.java:60)
   at cc.arduino.contributions.packages.ContributionInstaller.install(ContributionInstaller.java:105)
   at cc.arduino.contributions.packages.ui.ContributionManagerUI.lambda$onInstallPressed$2(ContributionManagerUI.java:172)
   ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
   at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
   at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3444)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3437)
   at cc.arduino.utils.network.FileDownloader.readStreamCopyTo(FileDownloader.java:268)
   at cc.arduino.utils.network.FileDownloader.openConnectionAndFillTheFile(FileDownloader.java:247)
   at cc.arduino.utils.network.FileDownloader.downloadFile(FileDownloader.java:182)
   at cc.arduino.utils.network.FileDownloader.download(FileDownloader.java:129)
   at cc.arduino.contributions.DownloadableContributionsDownloader.download(DownloadableContributionsDownloader.java:142)
   ... 5 more
```

Once it downloaded the package and then again halts during downloading the library. The download had to be stopped using task manager every time after a halt. I have a 100 Mbps OFC connection, so speed is not the issue. Even uninstalled and reinstalled Arduino IDE couple of time without any improvement.
I could install the package via git cloning but it requires installing lots of additional libraries and finally giving lots of warning, duplicate header and package and sometimes error in compiling.
[[Installation Error Screen][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur7i3.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur7i3.jpg)
So frustrating
[image]

Comment: do you ask how you can fix the Arduino IDE source code?

Comment: No, I want to install ESP8266 board via board manager. I like to know if there is any fault on my end or the server side? Now it stopped after downloading 32 MB out of 34 MB. Really frustrating.